# Why is this question closed?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

Could someone explain to me why this article is off topic? To me it appears to be on the topic of the Raspberry Pi. It could be displayed on a different Linux related site but i think it would be voted down there too because it could be on this site.

Comment: the link to the question is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the site's [FAQ](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically this section:

> Questions directly related to Linux/Unix issues. Please use the Unix &
>   Linux Exchange.

just because it runs on a Pi or makes use of a Pi in some way does not make it on topic. Creating and limiting access to an acess point is not substantially different on a PI than on a Debian or Ubuntru box. Therefore, your question belongs on either superuser or Unix and Linux as I mentioned.